# How to make a CAshapeLayer fit into a button?

Tags: swift, uibutton, cashapelayer

I tried to create a function inside a custom UIButton class to add a shape to an existing button.

```
func drawStartButton(){
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: -100))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: -50))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.close()

    shape.path = path.cgPath
    shape.fillColor = redColor.cgColor
    shape.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(shape)

}
```

So far no problem... BUT when i add the layer to the button, the layer is to big of course! How can i "autoresize" the layer to its button? I did expect something like

`shape.frame = self.bounds` 
... but the path still keeps the same size as without the self.bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to subclass the button and then layout your layer in `layoutSubviews` which gets called when your surrounding frame changes.

```swift
final class StartButton: UIButton {

    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

But I'm noticing that you are dictating a giant shape in terms of your `CGPoint`s. You might have to subclass the layer, too, and redraw based on your bounds in `layoutSublayers`.

Comment: I totally agree with u, that this is not the best way to do this. I am quite new to SWIFT and i just played around with these CAshapeLayers. I thought it would be the easiest way to draw something and just fit it onto the button frame. Do u know a tutorial how to redraw a button and then modify the path to make it look like i want? Because I can only find something like UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)) ... but i cant imagine how i can create some more complex formes with that functions from UIBezierPath.

Comment: I think i got what u mean...  it should look something like this, by sending the dimensions of the button to the layers sublcass nad redrawing them....  import UIKit

class CustomShapeCAshapeLayer: CAShapeLayer {

    func shapeButton(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint....)
    }
}

Comment: Try just updating the frame in `layoutSubviews` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomShapeCAshapeLayer: CAShapeLayer {

    func shapeButton(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height + 30))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height + 30))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.close()

        self.fillColor = redColor.cgColor
        self.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

main:

```
let layer = CustomShapeCAshapeLayer()
layer.shapeButton(width: startGameButton.frame.width, height: startGameButton.frame.height)
startGameButton.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```